# How to copy form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code which works, but hard coded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    var title      = this.elements.title.value;
    var owner      = this.elements.owner.value;
    var users      = this.elements.users.value;
    var groups     = this.elements.groups.value;
    var begin_date = this.elements.from.value;
    var end_date   = this.elements.to.value;
    var anchor     = this.elements.anchor.value;
    var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';

    var aform      = $('form[name="create_form"]');
```

I need `aform` for a nested Ajax call later on.

**Question**

How do I construct `aform` so it is not hard coded? There are many forms on the page.

It should contain

```
    var title      = this.elements.title.value;
    var owner      = this.elements.owner.value;
    var users      = this.elements.users.value;
    var groups     = this.elements.groups.value;
    var begin_date = this.elements.from.value;
    var end_date   = this.elements.to.value;
    var anchor     = this.elements.anchor.value;
    var type = $(this).find('input:radio[name="ctype"]:checked').val() || '';
```

and should work with the nested Ajax call later on.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: aform.serialize(),
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do yo mean with "construct `aform`"?

Comment: @RoToRa : `aform` now contains the form info from the form `name="create_form"`. Which is the same information I gather above using `this`. How do I wrap the many `element` extractions into an object that can be used with `data: aform.serialize(),` ?

Comment: I still don't understand. If `$('form[name="create_form"]')` is the same as `$(this)` what don't you use it? Maybe you are looking for `.serializeArray()`?

Comment: @RoToRa : That's a very good question! In fact, you just solved the problem =) if you post `var aform = $(this);` then I can close =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aform = $(this);
```

(as requested by Sandra :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all this by yourself. Jquery itself has a [form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) , which submits the form via ajax. It is self explainatory.

Comment: Can this be done with form name instead of form ID? The form ID's are auto-generated and I don't know then before hand. But I know the form names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of converting some form elements into a JSON object - although Abdul Kader's suggestion is better if you only want to do this to send the data in JSON format.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="example">
    <p><label>Name<br><input type="text" name="name" value="Bob"></p>
    <p><label>Happy<br><input type="checkbox" name="happy" checked></p>
    <p><textarea name="information">Some text "data" here!</textarea>
</form>
<div id="exampleOutput">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function exampleFormData() {
        var formData;
        var jsonString = "({";
        var jsonCount = 0;

        // This will add each input to a JSON string
        $("#example input, #example textarea").each( function () {
            if (jsonCount > 0) {
                jsonString += ", "
            }
            var key = this.name;
            var value = this.value;
            jsonString += key + ': "' + value.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"';
            jsonCount++;
        });
        jsonString += "})"

        // This converts the string into a JSON object
        formData = eval(jsonString);

        // Now you can use the formData JSON object...
        $("#exampleOutput").html(formData.name + " " + formData.happy + " " + formData.information);
    }

    exampleFormData();
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `.serializeArray()`, only more insecure?

Comment: Is `aform` in my case just an JSON string? Could I then use JSON's encode function to create it?